# Error in entries per page counting plugin

Tags: solspace, add-on-development, supersearch

I'm working on a quick plugin to output where you are in a paginated list of entries but am having problems doing mathematical calculations on plugin parameters when one of them is using `{super_search_total_results}`.

This is what I have so far:

```
$output        = '';
$per_page      = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('page_num'); // e.g. 9
$total_entries = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('total_results'); // e.g. 50
$output        = $per_page + $total_entries;

return $this->return_data = $output;
```

And in the template I have:

```
{exp:td_tours_advanced_count
    page_num='6'
    url_segment="{last_segment}"
    total_results='{super_search_total_results}'
}
```

So with the above, if my total results are 14 then the expected result of `$output` should be 20 but instead I get 6. If I set `$output` to just equal `$total_entries` then the result is 14.

It's only when I try to use `$total_entries` in a mathematical operation that it always seems to evaluate to 0, i.e. if I do `*` or `/` I get 0.

But if I change the plugin parameter in the template to

```
{exp:td_tours_advanced_count
    page_num='6'
    url_segment="{last_segment}"
    total_results='14'
}
```

then the `$output` is as expected and all other mathematical operations work correctly. I've tried adding `parse='inward'` to the plugin but to no avail.

So why is that `{super_search_total_results}` parses OK as a string but when trying to use it as an integer, it always returns 0 (I've tried converting it to an integer/float but the output is still 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I update the question I find the answer. For some reason `{super_search_total_results}` as the plugin parameter doesn't work but `{exp:super_search:results limit="1"}{super_search_total_results}{/exp:super_search:results}` does.

It would still be interesting to know why the first only works when trying to output the string directly and not when using it in mathematical operations, but the latter does.